# Drawing graphs in PHP or HTML

Tags: php, html, css

I'm looking for quite a specific technique.

**The short of it:**

I need HTML which can generate a line chart, as shown below (but without the background image. That is totally irrelevant)

[image: Image example]

However, I want to make it in HTML, without Javascript or Flash and in a way that the dots can be hovered to show more information.

**The long of it:**

The image shown above comes from the website [jpgraph.net](http://jpgraph.net/). That is a PHP library for creating charts. The downside of that however, is that it generates images. Since you have no clue of knowing where the dots are going to end up, you can't estimate where the hovers should be made.

Ofcourse there are also loads of javascript ways of doing this, but the graph should also work without javascript.

Flash is out of the question, since it should also work on tablets (read iPads)... And because it is flash...

All the information shown in the graph is generated by an external system. That means that the code should work and change the graph, depending on the information put in there.

---

**EDIT:**

I'm aware of the fact that it is easily done with javascript, and my fallback would be to offer a javascript version and as a fallback the php version. However, I'm hoping to find a way which doesn't need a fallback. Using 1 script to do the same task would be better than using two.

Comment: I believe that HTML5 canvas also relies on javascript.

Comment: What about generating an image and a `<map>` element? You can define round regions in the imagemap and give them a title so that info will be displayed if they're hovered. See here: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_map.asp

Comment: The problem with that is that I don't know what the regions are, which makes it quite hard to place them. Since the image will be generated based on value's I don't know beforehand, I can't place those map area's.

Comment: Do the values on the axis change or are they consistent?

Comment: They change. I need one piece of code to generate multiple graphs. The amount of graphs could go into the 10 to 50 range.

Comment: I don't really see a way of doing this without javascript help.  Without javascript, there isn't really a way to create what you want visually with CSS in a dynamic way.  That means with CSS alone, you would have to create css that covers tons of different possibilities, which means bloated code, way too much work etc.

Why do you want to do this without the use of javascript?

Comment: I was afraid of that yes. The reason for wanting it without javascript is that the client for whom this functionality is made requires us to make a site viewable under all circumstances. That means even for the 1.5% of people not using javascript.

Comment: @SanderKoedood - huh? Of course you do. You already know where the vertices of the graph are, from when you drew it. What's stopping you from generating the image and the markup for the image-map from the same script? Create an image with a random name, save on the server. Create the markup for a page that contains a reference to the image you just saved and the `<map>` that makes use of that image.

Comment: @enhzflep You are right. However, that would probably mean I would have to write the code to create the graph myself as well, wouldn't it? That would be quite a time consuming job I think. Added to that, it would probably flood the server, if there is an image generated at each page load. Could you make an example of how you would go about that?

Comment: @SanderKoedood - wouldn't you already have the data that you had to pass to the function that drew the graph? Would you not simply pass this same data to the function that you create, that produces the markup for the `<map>`? I suppose you could use any one of a number of different schemes for generating the fileNames. If you used a php script as the source for the images, you could set the headers to the image type, output the image with imageread and then delete the image from your server. Browser caching should mean the image wouldn't be requested a second time if the user reloads.

Comment: @enhzflep Good point about the image. The data used to create the graph don't represent image the point coordinates however. They represent a value which need to be placed in logical order of each other. A PHP library would handle that, which means it translates values to coordinates. However, I'm not sure there's a library which actually returns those coordinates.

Comment: Here's what I would do: add a graph image to the html page without the dots, since the dots are coming from a server as you said, I would have php go through and add them based on relative positioning to the graph image's container.  If you want a pop up when the image is hovered over, that's javascript or ajax for client side, and php if you want that pop up to have data or come from the server.

Comment: @Sander, well, unless it used a compiled binary to do so, you could just look at the source. In fact, you could just copy the source and replace the image output section with one that simply output an array of 2d pixel coordinates. Or preferably (for execution efficiency) - you could adapt it to save the image and return the array of data points.

Comment: @enhzflep Yes, I think that will be the short of it. I was hoping to find someone who'd have done something like this before, offering me the holy grail of sorts. That could save me a lot of development time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For those still interested: I fixed this using the [jpgraph.net](http://jpgraph.net/) library. It's a php library which allows you to draw graphs on the server using data you get from somewhere else.

As [enhzflep](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1630963/enhzflep) pointed out, since you have the data, you can calculate where the points will end up. This is however, quite a tedious job, but it's working in javascript-less browsers.

Answer (score 1):

You should check out [**Charts.js**](http://www.chartjs.org/) by Nick Downie.
It has simple HTML5 Charts using the canvas element -

Charts and Graphs Included:

1. Bar Chart
2. Doughnut Chart
3. Line Graph
4. Pie Chart
5. Polar-area Chart
6. Radar Chart

Read the documentation here: http://www.chartjs.org/docs/

and download on GitHub here: https://github.com/nnnick/Chart.js

Hope I Helped

Comment: Thanks for the advice, however, I won't be able to use javascript for this functionality. So this is no option for me.

Comment: I don't think there is a way to achieve this without javascript

Comment: may I ask, why do you want to do this without javascript? as it will be nearly impossible to recreate with pure CSS and HTML.

Comment: As stated in the comments above: The reason for wanting it without javascript is that the client for whom this functionality is made requires us to make a site viewable under all circumstances. That means even for the 1.5% of people not using javascript.

Comment: No offense @SanderKoedood but as a business person myself, this is where you go to the client and say, no, we aren't supporting the 1.5%.  It's very likely that the demographics of people who have javascript disabled doesn't match with your target audience anyways, so it's likely even less in your case also.

Comment: @Michael None taken. Normally I would agree. However, when working for the government, those kind of points are taken slightly different. It's simply no option to say that we can't support them.

Comment: how about you just display the data in a different way to the people without javascript?

Comment: because the only other way would be to implement images of each graph, which would be a pain..

Comment: @SAMTHEMAN999 As stated in my original question, you can create an image with just the data which needs to go into the graph. That would be done with the php library. And you are right, showing the data in an alternative way would be the way to go, but I'm hoping for the perfect fix, if it exists.